# How do I create a Service Hook Web Hook in Azure DevOps using a client certificate?

Tags: azure-devops, client-certificate

the service I want to connect my webhook to requires a client certificate when communicating via SSL/TLS. I already downloaded the certificate files, how can I add my certificate to the service hook / web hook of my azure devops project settings.

I created a Service -> WebHook but cannot find a field on how to set my client cert?